# Get recursive nested template call to work in Angular 2?

Tags: html, templates, typescript, angular, angular-directive

I hope the title isn't misleading too much as I have no idea how else to call it, but here's the problem:

I am developing an app with Angular 2 and use the nested templates (hope that's the right name for them) in several instances.
Now the issue I have is that my app consists of several "widgets" which can contain other widgets. This can create a sort of circle in the template calls.

Example:

home.html:

```
<div> some html stuff </div>
<widget1 *ng-for="#widget of widgetList" [widget]="widget"></widget1>
```

widget1.html:

```
<div> some html stuff unique to widget1 </div>
<div *ng-if="widget.widgetSubList">
  <div *ng-for="#widget of widget.widgetSubList">
    <div [ng-switch]="widget.type">
      <p *ng-switch-when="2"><widget2 [widget]="widget"></></widget2></p>
      <p *ng-switch-when="3"><widget3 [widget]="widget"></></widget3></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

widget2.html

```
<div> some html stuff unique to widget2 </div>
<div *ng-if="widget.widgetSubList">
  <div *ng-for="#widget of widget.widgetSubList">
    <div [ng-switch]="widget.type">
      <p *ng-switch-when="1"><widget1 [widget]="widget"></></widget1></p>
      <p *ng-switch-when="3"><widget3 [widget]="widget"></></widget3></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

widgetSubList is a property of the widget that is filled if it has sub-widgets, the ng-if does work in this case and doesn't crash the code if there are no sub-widgets.

That's the point where the whole thing crashes since it creates the mentioned "circle" of widgets containing widgets that have been in the above part of the tree already since widget1 can call widget2 which can call widget1 again.
I can't change that structure since it's predetermined by the API I use in this case.

So now the question: Is there a way to have this work?

Since all widgets require different implementations, I can't really work around it without creating one giant html file filled with ng-ifs, which I would like to avoid.

PS: I edited the example a bit further to represent the code better.
the @Input part is present in the .ts files.

Right now, I only read out one additional level of sub-widgets from the API for test purposes.

Comment: Some concrete error message?

Comment: I have a ng-for call in my home.html, somewhat like this: `*ng-for="#widget of widgetList"`. All the error tells me is that it can't call the property "forEach" of an undefined or Nullreference. So my guess is that the "circle" call breaks and it therefor messes up the ng-for.

Comment: Can cou create a plunker that allows to reproduce?

Comment: I can try, might get a bit complex to reproduce it entirely though. I can't do so right now either, but if needed I will see to it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

What is a bit strange is that you don't have a loop of widgets within the `widget1.html` and `widget2.html` files. With your implement, you always remain on the same widget metadata, so it's normal that you have an infinite loop...

As a matter of fact, you need to have a recursive structure that would allow to define the structure of your component:

```
widgetList
  widget
    children
      widget
        children
      widget
        children
  widget
    children
      widget
        children
  (...)
```

So when the current widget won't have children, the recursive loop will end.

So I would refactor your templates like this (for example for `widget1.html`):

```
<div> some html stuff unique to widget1 </div>
<div *ng-for="#subWidget of widget.children">
  <div [ng-switch]="subWidget.type">
    <p *ng-switch-when="2"><widget2 [widget]="subWidget"></widget2></p>
    <p *ng-switch-when="3"><widget3 [widget]="subWidget"></widget3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Each widget would have an input corresponding to the widget metadata:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'widget1',
  (...)
})
export class Widget1Component {
  @Input()
  widget: any;
}
```